# Best practice to create automatic reports with Cumulocity

Tags: reporting, iot, cumulocity

I am wanting to create automated reports using the data I have collected with Cumulocity. I would like to automate the creation of the reports so that they aggregate accumulated timeseries, alarm & event data into a single report that could be automatically sent to relevant parties by e-mail on a fixed time interval (weekly, for example).

I understand how to do this with the APIs that Cumulocity provides, but I am interested in experiences of more specific implementations (I imagine I am not the first person thinking about this). Should the data that I want to aggregate be retrieved with CEL (Cumulocity Event Language) and then the report created in the desired format (pdf) with my own script? Is it possible to host this kind of script in Cumulocity or do I have to host it myself?

Answer (score 1):

There is a quite new feature related to the reporting in cockpit (excel/csv export). This can now also be scheduled and send via mail. Maybe this is already something that helps you.

[Scheduled export configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7Kaf.png)

Comment: It's available since 8.9: https://support.cumulocity.com/hc/en-us/articles/115011970227-Release-Notes-for-Cumulocity-8-9

Comment: Hi, thank you for this information! Although this seems useful in general, I was looking for a way to generate the report in a format of my choosing (for a client, for example). For this reason, the mere excel is not enough for my purposes.